# Warp two row with a class after query

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, foreach

I want to warp every two row with a class. So I saw some guideline from here and googling and found foreach array_chunk to do this. And I tried as below which can't display any result. Without foreach its work well. Were is my wrong here please?

[image]

In the above picture that I want to do; my every two category warp with a class. And add a divider after each top category.

Here is my tried:

```
echo '<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-large row">';
    $sql = "SELECT id,name FROM main_cata ORDER BY id ASC";
    $execute = $dbh->query("$sql");
    $rowcount = $execute->num_rows ;
    $row = $dbh->query($sql) ; 

    while ($row = $execute->fetch_assoc()) {

         foreach (array_chunk($row, 2, true) as $array){
             echo'<li class="col-sm-3">';

             foreach($array as $rows){
                  echo '<ul><li class="dropdown-header">'.$rows->name.'</li>';

                  $sql2 = "SELECT id,name,page FROM catagory WHERE m_cata = '".$rows->id."' ORDER BY id ASC";
                  $execute2 = $dbh->query("$sql2");
                  $rowcount2 = $execute2->num_rows ;
                  $row = $dbh->query($sql) ; 
                  while ($row = $execute2->fetch_assoc()) {
                  $cid = $row['id'];
                  $cname = $row['name'];    
                  $page = $row['page'];
                  echo '<li><a href="#">'.$cname.'</a></li>';
                  }
                  echo '<li class="divider"></li></ul>';
              }
              echo '</li>'; 
         }       
    }
echo '</ul>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while ($row = $execute->fetch_assoc()) {
```

**fetch_assoc** returns 1 row (id, name) from the query, then you are using the result and spliting in 2 (https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php), What you can do is, make a counter instead of the array chunk that resets every time it reachs 2.

```
foreach (array_chunk($row, 2, true) as $array){
```

The content of $row is, for example, array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'Category 1').

```
foreach($array as $rows){
```

You are iterating again without needing to.

---

A simple version:

```
counter = 0;
echo "<ul>";
while (row = execute->fetch_assoc()) {
     if (counter == 0) {
        echo "init li";
     }

    echo "subinit li";
    get subcategories
    while (row2 = execute2->fetch_assoc()) {
         print content
    }
    echo "subend li";    

    if (counter == 2) {
        counter == 0;
        echo "end li";
    } else {
        counter++;
        echo "divider";
    }
}
echo "</ul>";
```